# RTMP Stream in to MS Teams Seldom Works

Tags: rtmp

I'm attempting to send an RTMP stream from my encoder (Wirecast or OBS) to an MS Teams Town Hall event. The Town Hall event has RTMP-in turned on. However, when I start streaming from my encoder, Microsoft's RTMP server (`MSRTC/1.0`) consistently drops the connection after the encoder sends the stream metadata in the `@setDataFrame` message. The server first stops the TCP/IP connection with a `[FIN/ACK]` packet and after the encoder continues to send data, it finally blasts back a bunch of TCP `[RST]` packets.

Microsoft's server just does this over and over with each connection attempt by my encoder.

- It does this regardless of the encoder I pick or its streaming settings
- It does it no matter which network I'm connecting from (corporate, home, tethered phone)
- It continues this way for 10 or 20 minutes and then finally accepts a connection from my encoder.

After it accepts the connection from the encoder once, I can then connect again with any other encoder from any other network or device and their server will accept the stream.

I noticed that traceroute to their server (emea.rtmpingest.mcr.teams.microsoft.com), places it in Dublin. Our corporate headquarters so far as Microsoft is concerned is in Berlin. However, this office and our ISP is in the U.S.

Has anyone else observed this behavior with MS Teams Town Hall events with RTMP-In? Any idea how to fix it?

[image: traceroute to server]